# GitHub action release tag

Tags: github, yaml, devops, release, github-actions

Upon creating a release in GitHub I trigger a GitHub action. In this action, I would like to get some data from the release, is this possible? For example, I would like to get the tag and then use this tag as the NuGet package version. Is there a way to get this data from the job?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `${{ github.ref }}` or `${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}`

Example:

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10

jobs:
  deploy:    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: NameOfYourArtifact
      - name: Create release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          body: TODO
          draft: true
          prerelease: false

      - name: Upload Release Asset
        id: upload-release-asset 
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
          asset_path: NameOfYourArtifact.exe
          asset_name: NameOfYourArtifact.exe
          asset_content_type: application/octet-stream
```

This action is executed when a new tag is created with a name like v*.

To trigger the action:

```
git push origin v1.0.0
```

Comment: great example thanks. I see github.ref returns 'refs/tags/1.9.9' in my case, do I then apply regex to remove the 'ref/tags' part?

Comment: It depends, if you use it in `release_name` the refs/tags is trimmed automatically, if you want to use it in a custom step, you may want to extract it with regex.

Comment: Ah it's in ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}

Answer (score 7):

Here is the 2022 answer on how to get a tag name from GitHub.

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
jobs:
  github-example-tags:
    steps:
     - name: GitHub Tag Name example
       run: |
         echo "Tag name from GITHUB_REF_NAME: $GITHUB_REF_NAME"
         echo "Tag name from github.ref_name: ${{  github.ref_name }}"
```

See

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

github.ref_name returns the branch name on my action.